# How to get SQL Database Status in Azure with Log Analytics

Tags: sql-server, azure, kql

I would like to show whether an Azure SQL database is online or not in an Azure Workbook.

Is this information available to resource metric/log analytics workspace so that I can show it in an Azure Workbook.

Could you provide me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a feature or function to check the Azure SQL database Status.

Once the Azure SQL database created, it will be alive or online all the time. Unless you manually delete or pause it(Elastic pool).

HTH.